# Using Cypress and/or mocha (or mocha-chai) to check for not containing a word but NOT substring

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, cypress

I am trying to using `Cypress` (which contains `mocha`, plus I am using `mocha-chai`) to check for a series of words *NOT* included in a phrase. That is because for example, I have three `<div>`s and I want to check

- that words in div1 are present in div1 but not in div2 and div3;
- that words in div2 are present in div2 but not in div1 and div3;
- that words in div3 are present in div3 but not in div1 and div2.

To do that I'm using `.contain` and `.not.contain` but unluckily they find some substrings:

if I have

```
// div1
<div> 
    ...
    The perfect professionist for you
</div>

// div2
<div>
    ...
    Good professionists are ready here
</div>
```

I do

```
expect(div1).to.contain('professionist')        // true
expext(div1).to.not.contain('professionists')   // true
```

this is fine, but

```
expect(div2).to.contain('professionists')       // true
expect(div2).to.not.contain('professionist')    // false!
```

will fail.

Is there a way using cypress, mocha or anything similar to do a check on entire word but not substring?

Comment: So you want to check for the word `professionist` and it should fail as the original sentence has the word `professionists` an extra 's'. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, but it's just an example (since I have to do different checks in a different language) :) the idea is that one anyway: the 4th test should return `true` because I just want to check the entire word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Word Boundary: \b

More general is regex [word boundary](https://javascript.info/regexp-boundary)

```js
cy.get('div').eq(1).invoke('text')
  .then(div2Text => expect(div2Text).to.not.match(/\bprofessionist\b/))  // passes
```

or passing the word into the regex (**note** requires `\\b` for propper translation)

```js
const word = 'professionist'
const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${word}\\b`)

cy.get('div').eq(1).invoke('text')
  .then(div2Text => expect(div2Text).to.not.match(regex))  // passes

cy.get('div').eq(1).invoke('text')
  .should('not.match', regex)      // passes
```

---

#### Your pastebin

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />
 
before(() => {})
 
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.viewport(2048, 1080)
})
describe('Test', () => {
  it('simple test', () => {
    let div = document.createElement('div')
    let content = document.createTextNode('Good professionists are ready here')
    div.appendChild(content)

    try {

      let word = 'professionist'
      let regex = new RegExp(`\\b${word}\\b`)
      expect(div.innerText).not.to.match(regex) // passes 

      word = 'professionists'
      regex = new RegExp(`\\b${word}\\b`)
      expect(div.innerText).to.match(regex)  // passes

    } catch (error) {
      Cypress.log(error)
    }
  })
})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you man, I tried with ` /\b(\w*?(\b${word}\b)\w*)\b/ ` but for some reasons it does not accept it; instead your expression works flawlessy

Comment: Yeah, it's the the RegExp constructor needs `"\\"` from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp)

Comment: arrrggghh that's why

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to do that. For assertion, you have to use `match()`.

```
var regexValue = "(?<!\S)word(?!\S)"
var actualRegexValue = new RegExp(regexValue.replace("word", "professionist"))
cy.get('div2').invoke('text').then((text) => {
    expect(text).to.match(actualRegexValue)
})
```

Your regex `/(?<!\S)professionist(?!\S)/` will only search for the string `professionist` in the sentence and not anything else not even `professionists`.

Comment: sounds good! how can I edit it to make it parametric? I tried with ` regEx = /(?<!\S)${singleValue}(?!\S)/ `   (note that ` are included) and `expect(div).to.not.match(new RegExp(regEx))` but doesnt seem to work

Comment: Also note that I used to.not.match

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for some reason :( when I change in your (updated) code "professionist" with "professionists", the test is marked as passed, which shouldn't be

Comment: The regex that we have will only match a single word. So the assertion should be on the same line. So you have to use `to.match`.

Comment: Well, I'm actually using `to.match`, I just changed `new RegExp(regexValue.replace("word","professionist"))` with `new RegExp(regexValue.replace("word","professionists"))` -just to do a reverse test- and I am expecting that the test would return `true` but sadly it doesn't

Comment: Please post your entire test script along with the html dom, in that case I would be able to help you better.

Comment: Are you extracting the innertext and then checking it right? I have updated the asnwer.

Comment: well I created a small pastebin: https://pastebin.com/gExYNwJF . If I change in `actualRegexValue` the word from 'professionist' to 'professionists' I would expect a `true` result, but doesnt happen

Comment: Change `expect(div).to.match(actualRegexValue)` to `cy.get('div').invoke('text').then((text) => {
    expect(text).to.match(actualRegexValue)
})`. You have to extract the inner text first and then match it with regex.

Comment: This way it expects that the entire phrase you write inside the regex is the same as the text in the div I think: it says `
expected '\n \n This is the default blank page.\n To test your web application:\n \n Start your app's server\n \n \n cy.visit()\n \n your app\n \n Begin writing tests\n \n    ' to match /(?<!S)professionists(?!S)/ `